# ViewController reference in AppDelegate using Storyboard

Tags: macos, cocoa, storyboard

I am writing a one view application based on storyboard.

I have added a toolbar, clicking on buttons messages are received into the AppDelegate.

I need to forward them to the ViewController but I am not able to get a reference to it in the AppDelegate.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as that:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

   if (_viewController==nil) {
       _viewController = (ViewController *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainWindow].contentViewController;
   }
}
```